# Remove product at cart

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am use woocommerce shotcode in shop page [woocommerce_cart]. I am try to remove product using ajax. How can find product id and cart remove function is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {  
     $( document ).on( 'click', '.product-remove .remove', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
       var unit_id =// how can find product id;
      e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
             beforeSend: function() { $('#wait').show(); },
            data: {catremovpid: unit_id}, //Pass the id
            url:'http://mysiteurl.com/one-page/test/',
              success: function(data){  
                  $('.bd_woo_cart').empty().prepend('');
                 $('.bd_woo_cart').append(data);                 
                  console.log(data); 
              },
              error: function(data){
                console.log('error');
              }
        });
   });
});
```

And php function is

```
if (isset($_POST["catremovpid"])){

     $data = $_POST["catremovpid"];

     $prod_unique_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($data );
    // Remove it from the cart by un-setting it
    unset( WC()->cart->cart_contents[$prod_unique_id] );
    echo do_shortcode ('[woocommerce_cart]');    
}
```

But product is not remove on cart. But this code is work on cart page. But on the shop page this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using remove_cart_item() method instead of php unset:

```
if (isset($_POST["catremovpid"])){

     $data = $_POST["catremovpid"];

     $prod_unique_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id($data );
    // Remove it from the cart by un-setting it
    WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($prod_unique_id); 
    echo do_shortcode ('[woocommerce_cart]');    
}
```

Comment: First please tell me  (var unit_id =// how can find product id;) how can find the product id on remove button. but i am check on remove_cart_item function is not working..

Comment: This code working on cart page but i am working on costume page (like shop  page).

Comment: Okay i got  it. But you can use the same technique that in plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php .  Instead of using woocommerce_cart shortcode, create your own custom shortcode, and use the code in the given file.  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { .... } - you will find all needed functions there (to get ID, ready function for remove link etc...)

Comment: Please help me ... give me some code check online website http://testdeveloper.website/one-page/

Comment: i gave you the code, it is inside plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php.